# Does Kotlin delay use a dispatcher internally to unblock the caller thread?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This is some test code I am using to learn kotlin coroutines. The code works as expected and takes about 1 Second to print the sum, but now If I replace delay(1000) by a blocking call like a network request, then the code takes about 10 seconds to print the sum ( each call takes around 1 second), but if I wrap the network call in a withContext and use the IO dispatcher it takes 1 second to print the sum, because it is run on a different thread. Does the delay function use some kind of a dispatcher to unblock the thread?

```
suspend fun asyncDoubleFn(num: Int): Int {
    delay(1000)
    return num * 2
}


fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        val tt = measureTimeMillis {
            val results = mutableListOf<Deferred<Int>>()
            for (num in 0..10) {
                val result = async { asyncDoubleFn(num + 1) }
                results.add(result)
            }
            val sum = results.map { it.await() }.reduce { acc, i -> acc + i }
            println("[SUM]: $sum")
        }

        println("[TT]: $tt")
    }


    launch {
        println("Another coroutine")
    }

    println("Main Code")


}
```

Comment: Source: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/common/kotlinx-coroutines-core-common/src/Delay.kt#L71

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a little detailed explanation , since I am new to this concept, but am familiar with JS async await(Mostly do front-end JS). I mainly want to understand if we can take a blocking API like java.net.URL and run it in suspend mode.

Comment: You can, take a look at [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html). I'm not familiar enough with the details to fully explain how it works, but [there was a good talk on this at KotlinConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrrUCSi72E8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the delay function use some kind of a dispatcher to unblock the thread?

Not just `delay`. All suspendable functions interact with the dispatcher.

The question you should ask is: "Which dispatcher is in charge here?"

And the answer is: `runBlocking` installs its own dispatcher that dispatches to the thread it is called on. Both `launch` and `async` in your code inherit it.

With this in mind:

> If I replace delay(1000) by a blocking call like a network request, then the code takes about 10 seconds to print the sum (each call takes around 1 second)

Each blocking call will hold on to the single thread of the dispatcher. It won't be able to do any other work while being blocked.

> but if I wrap the network call in a `withContext` and use the `IO` dispatcher it takes 1 second to print the sum, because it is run on a different thread

Yes, this changes the dispatcher, problem solved.

So, what does `delay` do? It suspends the current coroutine (the one that `async` launched) and returns the control to the dispatcher, which can now go on to resume your loop and start the next coroutine.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this clears most of my confusion, you said delay suspends the current coroutine and returns control to the dispatcher, does delay use some kind of a task queue scheduling to run the code after the delay time elapses , does it work like setTimeout in JS?.

Comment: It works pretty much exactly like that. The `runBlocking` dispatcher establishes an event queue and an event loop that drains the queue and handles the events. Just like the Android looper or the Swing event loop or the JS event loop.